# can AWS event bridge handle high QPS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to implement a scheduling service that periodically perform scheduled jobs in a multi-tenant environment, and i am stuck on choosing the tools. In my prior experience I would use celery to deal with asynchrounous task queue but since our tech stack is on AWS I am looking for aws alternatives. Looks like EventBridge supports Publish/Multiple Subscriber pattern, but i dont know if it can scale with TPS goes up ? I did not find any docs about scalibilty on eventBridge. Also, is eventBridge a task queue ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the [recently launched EventBridge Scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-eventbridge-scheduler/) could solve your problem:

> This is a new capability from Amazon EventBridge that allows you to
> create, run, and manage scheduled tasks at scale. With EventBridge
> Scheduler, you can schedule one-time or recurrently tens of millions
> of tasks across many AWS services without provisioning or managing
> underlying infrastructure.